Does Deno's FsFile.readable automatically close the file when the stream is exhausted?
Given the following code:
const file = await Deno.open(fsPathname, { read: true })
return new Response(file.readable, { status: 200 })

Will FsFile.readable automatically close the file once the stream has been exhausted? The documentation doesn't mention this. If the answer is 'no' then I don't see how you close the file without seriously unneeded complexity.

Yes, the file resource associated to its readable stream will be closed when the stream encounters EOF.
The documentation is currently lacking, but a PR has been created to improve this and also to add an option to prevent closure of the file resource if desired.

PR: denoland/deno#24247 — feat: add preventCloseOnEOF option
Direct link to updated JSDoc description in the associated commit


What if an error is encountered before EOF? Could that cause a resource leak, or does it close the file in that case as well?

^ @Chris_F That's a different question than the one you asked. Questions on SO should be singularly focused. You are welcome to ask a new one if you can't find it on this site. That said… I encourage you do do a test and determine the answer instead of relying on something someone said on the internet so that you can have greater confidence in your program. Q/As on this site become outdated for lots of reasons.
